# Why is my regex displaying in alphabetical order?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

For my assignment, I am trying to scrape information off the following website: https://www.blueroomcinebar.com/movies/now-showing/.

My code needs to find movie names, times and posters. Both the movie times and posters appear to be displayed in the list I have created according to the order they appear in the HTML, however, the names seem to be in alphabetical order.

We are not allowed to use BeautifulSoup

This is my current code for scraping movies:

```py
from re import findall, finditer, MULTILINE, DOTALL
from urllib.request import urlopen

movies_name = []
movies_times = []
movies_image = []

movies_list = []

movies_page = urlopen("https://www.blueroomcinebar.com/movies/now-showing/").read().decode('utf-8')

#Add movies to Movies at Blue Room Screen
find_movie_names = findall(r'<h1>(.*?)</h1>', movies_page)
find_movie_times = findall(r'<p>([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} AM|PM)</p>', movies_page)
find_movie_image = findall(r'<div class="poster" style="background-image: url\((.*?)\)">', movies_page)

print(find_movie_names)
#Add movies to arrays
for movie in find_movie_names:
    movies_name.append(movie)
for movie in find_movie_times:
    movies_times.append(movie)
for movie in find_movie_image:
    movies_image.append(movie)

print(movies_name)
print(movies_image)

for movie in range(len(movies_name)):
    movies_list.append("{};{};{}".format(movies_name[movie], movies_times[movie], movies_image[movie - 1]))
```

Currently, the names are in the list in the order of

```py
['Aladdin', 'Avengers: Endgame', 'Chandigarh Amritsar Chandigarh', 'John Wick - Parabellum', 'Long Shot', 'Pokemon Detective Pikachu', 'Poms', 'The Hustle', 'Top End Wedding']
```

They should be in the order:

```py
['Avengers: Endgame', 'Long Shot', 'Pokemon Detective Pikachu', 'The Hustle', 'John Wick - Parabellum', 'Aladdin', 'Chandigarh Amritsar Chandigarh']
```

N.P.
There may be a movie that comes up a second time with the precursor OCAP. I'm not 100% sure why it has that but it seems to be some kind of special screening that rotates through different movies each day.

Comment: Hell yes, thank you. That worked

Comment: ?  What worked? Is this now solved?

Comment: Yeah, it's solved. They deleted their comment though for some reason

Comment: Is it worth your posting the solution?